# Sitecore: How do I retrieve the Mimetype / extension of a File field in XLST

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to know either the mimetype or the extensions of a file field so that I can place an appropriate icon next to the download link.

I've been able to do this fine in .NET code. Should I just convert this rendering to a sublayout?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a 3rd parameter to the sc:fld call lets you select a parameter from inside that field, you can then split the value on the '.' and go from there..

```xml
<xsl:variable name ="filename" select="sc:fld('file',.,'src')" />
Extension is : <xsl:value-of select="sc:SplitValue($filename,'.')[2]"/>
```

Hope this helps :D